# Finding Taylor series without using derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

If $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-1}$ then we can set $g(z)=e^{iz}$ and $h(z)=z^2-1$.
The Maclaurin expansion for $e^{iz}$ is $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$$
so $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$.

The geometric series for $-\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ is $$-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}$$

So we have the quotient $$-\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}}$$

Am I on the right track? I'd appreciate a hint on what to do next.

Comment: If $\left\vert z\right\vert < 1$ use ${1 \over  z^{2} - 1} = -\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{2k}$. If $\left\vert z\right\vert >1$ use ${1 \over  z^{2} - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{-2k - 2}$. Then, multiply the series. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $\left(-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}\right)$, not $-\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(iz)^n}{n!}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}}$.  You can now just multiply this out term by term.

Comment: Right, I have confused the functions to be multiplied/divided.